# Device to mount on used satellite TV dish to establish long distance wireless connection?

Tags: wifi, wireless, access-point

This is a common satellite TV dish for home use.  [image: directv dish]
*image (CC BY-SA 2.0)*

This is a device designed to be mounted on used satellite dishes such as this one.
[MikroTik LDF 5 ac (product page)](https://mikrotik.com/product/ldf_5_ac)

It seems that the idea is that you get two such satellite dishes, one of these devices to each one, and point the dishes straight at one another, thus establishing a long distance wifi link, recycling/reusing old equipment, and saving money all at the same time.

I'm totally for it!  I want to buy two of these. The price sounds reasonable to me, and I already have two old satellite dishes.  However...

The company has been accused of violating the software license (GPL) that governs the software inside their devices (it's called RouterOS and it's a custom Linux distribution).

I would rather give my business to a company that appreciates that their own business operation was made possible by the work of thousands of volunteers over many years.  If no such hardware company is available, then I'll want to do some price and feature comparison shopping.

So, what similar products exist?